# How to display a folder from Firebase Storage into a Wordpress webpage?

Tags: wordpress, firebase

I want to display files from Firebase Storage to a wordpress page.
Users can have access to the files, preview them and download them.

I'm stuck with the integration of firebase SDK in wordpress. I add this code in my template page.

```
  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <section class="firebase-file-list">
                <h2>Liste des Fichiers Firebase</h2>
                <ul id="firebase-files-list">
                        <!-- Les fichiers seront affichés ici automatiquement via 
 JavaScript -->
                </ul>
        </section>
  </main>
 </div>


    
    // Your Firebase configuration here
 const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: "XXXXXXXXX",
authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX",
projectId: "XXXXXXXXX",
storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX",
messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXX
appId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXX"
 };

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Use Firebase services with the global 'firebase' object
const storage = firebase.storage();
const storageRef = storage.ref('folder-name');
const filesList = document.getElementById('firebase-files-list');

storageRef.listAll().then((res) => {
res.items.forEach((item) => {
    // Créez un élément <li> pour chaque fichier et ajoutez-le à la liste
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const fileLink = document.createElement('a');
    item.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        fileLink.href = url; // Lien de téléchargement du fichier
        fileLink.textContent = item.name; // Nom du fichier
        listItem.appendChild(fileLink);
        filesList.appendChild(listItem);
    });
});
 }).catch((error) => {
console.error('Erreur lors de la récupération de la liste des fichiers :', error);
    });
```

Then I enqueue the scripts :

```
     wp_register_script('firebase-app', 
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-app.js', array(),true, 
  '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
    wp_enqueue_script('firebase-app'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_script('firebase-storage', 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-storage.js', array(),true, '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
    wp_enqueue_script('firebase-storage'); // Enqueue it!
```

But Nothing happen. I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

While your JavaScript code looks correct, it's essential to ensure that your Firebase SDK is loaded correctly. WordPress may have its own way of handling scripts and dependencies.

First, make sure that the Firebase SDK scripts are enqueued correctly using WordPress functions like '**wp_register_script**' and '**wp_enqueue_script**'. Double-check that the scripts are loading without any errors in the browser's console.

Next, confirm that the Firebase configuration (apiKey, authDomain, etc.) is correct and corresponds to your Firebase project. Any mismatch here can cause issues.

If everything looks good in terms of script loading and configuration, try to use WordPress's document-ready event for your JavaScript code to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded before your script runs. You can use the '**jQuery**' or '**window.onload**' event for this purpose.

Lastly, check your browser's developer console for any errors or warnings that might provide more specific information about what could be going wrong.